# Printing format with printf

Tags: c, printf

I'm doing the past exam and everything has been going well, I've finished the task, but I have some formatting problems.

What I get:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

It bothers me and I would be grateful if someone could come up with a solution.

My code for printing the array:

```
void printArray(int tab[][MAX], int n, int m) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf("%5d", j);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < 3 * n + 4; k++)
    {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d |", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d", tab[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What format does `"%5d"` specify?

Comment: The no. of the column of the array, I want it to be perfectly aligned with the numbers below it so that the user can comfortably read the number or row and column of an element.

Comment: Please do not add text (this also applies to text output) as pictures in your question. Instead add it as formatted text.

Comment: If you want to allign the columns in all rows, why do you mix `%5d` and `%3d`?

Answer (score 3):

The offset is off and `printf("%5d", j);` makes the heading numbers too wide.

Fix it by prepending the first line, but instead of `printf("%2d |", i);` that you use to prepend each line when printing the values, you can use a blank string, `printf("%2s |", "");`.

```c
void printArray(int tab[][MAX], int n, int m) {
    printf("%2s |", "");   // this fixes the offset

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf("%3d", j);  // and use the same width as when printing the values
    }
    
    // ...
```

Comment: About using printf("%2d |", i);
The i is the number of row and I want to keep it so user can see on the left whats the number of the row for an item.

Comment: @Veanty That's ok. I'm not suggesting that you change that. I suggest that you _add_ a line first in the function to fix the offset of the heading line only: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/96Yj4737K)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, with liberal use of width specifiers on the printf statements.

As you change the constant `COL_WIDTH`, the table should generally automatically adjust.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int tab[][4], int n, int m)
{
    const int COL_WIDTH = 4;
 
    printf("%*.*s|", COL_WIDTH, COL_WIDTH, "");
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf("%*d", COL_WIDTH, j);
    }

    printf("\n%.*s", COL_WIDTH*(n+1)+1, "----------------------------------------");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%*d |", COL_WIDTH-1, i);
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%*d", COL_WIDTH, tab[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int table[][4] = { { 1, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 2, 1} };

    printArray(table, 4, 4);
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
    |   0   1   2   3
---------------------
  0 |   1   2   1   2
  1 |   2   2   3   2
  2 |   1   3   2   3
  3 |   2   2   2   1
```